# How to find fishing bait?

Tags: project-zomboid

I made a fishing rod but fishing requires bait. Worms are sometimes but rarely found when looting kitchens. Digging in the ground does not seem to produce any. What is a good way to keep a reliable supply of fishing bait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to get bait is to dig with a trowel or by removing grass to obtain worms. This is faster than scavenging around in the town. Worms are always used up upon being used as bait, unlike other baits however.

Fishing tackle has durability, meaning you can use it more than once, cutting down on weight on bait as well. However, it is recommended that you wait until your fishing skill is mid to high level before using it.

https://pzwiki.net/wiki/Fishing#Bait

Comment: In addition to the above I have found that foraging can also give things like crickets which work fine as bait.